# pandas groupby extract top percent n data(descending)

Tags: pandas-groupby, percentile, top-n

1. I have some data like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class':['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','c','c'],'score':[3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14]})
df
```

```
  class score
0   a   3
1   a   5
2   b   6
3   b   7
4   a   8
5   a   9
6   b   10
7   c   11
8   c   14
```

I want to use groupby function extract top n% data(descending by score),i know the nlargest can make it,but the number of every group is different,so i don't know how to do it

---

I tried this function

```
top_n = 0.5
g = df.groupby(['class'])['score'].apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(int(round(top_n*len(x))),keep='all')).reset_index()
g
```

```
  class level_1 score
0   a   5      9
1   a   4      8
2   b   6      10
3   b   3      7
4   c   8      14
```

but it can not deal with big data(more than 10 million),it is very slow,how do i speed it,thank you!